# RT5 is taking slow

Tags: mysql, apache, rt

I hope you could help me. I've been experiencing slow performance of RT5. And I looked in the process, they were many processes of:

/usr/bin/perl -w /opt/rt5/sbin/rt-server.fcgi/

And they are consuming a lot of ram memory which makes the RT5 go slow for every transaction.

The mysql database is not in the same instance of the webserver. I'm using percona xtradb cluster and it is separated from the rt webserver.

I am confused if it is because they were many mysql transactions? But upon checking the mysql server, the process are okay.

I've configured the Apache fcgid.conf with  MaxRequestLen 10000000.

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  FcgidConnectTimeout 20

  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
    MaxRequestLen 10000000
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I badly need help.

Comment: Perhaps you need http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen instead?

Comment: Did you restart Apache after changing the value?

Comment: yes, i restarted the apache service but it always eating too much ram.